# How to get VAPID_PUBLIC_KEY and VAPID_PRIVATE_KEY for django webpush implementation?

Tags: django, reactjs, web-push

I want to implement web push notification in django project where frontend is implemented using react. I was following https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-send-web-push-notifications-from-django-applications this documentation but i didn't find the way to get VAPID_PUBLIC_KEY and VAPID_PRIVATE_KEY for WEBPUSH_SETTINGS. What is the way to get that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The DigitalOcean tutorial that you referred to instructs you to "navigate to the [web-push-codelab](https://web-push-codelab.glitch.me/) web application. Here, you’ll be given automatically generated keys. Copy the private and public keys." However, it seems like this web page is no longer available.

Another way to generate a VAPID key pair is to use the [web-push reference implementation](https://github.com/web-push-libs/web-push). First install the web-push npm package using `npm install web-push -g`, then run `web-push generate-vapid-keys` to get an output like:

```
Public Key:
BLEvwbQgAjaHjmXcJgpAmOpFCuR-m_BKJWhskZmbFYAQABA4ZrpLQ1UnNJVH_Zbmzjugmmts2I5kLt8wMKQlIME

Private Key:
cSTj1YJCOQGP-J6QLCr3gSkU2OPs39Dx3FtiBc6ZOYI
```

Obviously, do not use this key pair -- you're supposed to keep your private key, well.., private.

Comment: actually in my project i am only using  react js for frontend  and dajango for backend and not using any node module. Without using node module is it possible to get that?

Comment: You don't need to use the node module in your project -- you just need to use it once to generate the VAPID key pair.

Comment: npx web-push generate-vapid-keys